# Ms access VBA copy form data

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm currently making a ms access database and I have made a form where the user inputs data. I would like the user to be able to press a button which copies the label and the entered data so they can paste it elsewhere. I have found a project which achieves exactly what I want however I cannot seem to get it to work for my application. The code below is what I found online and this is the link to the thread. It is the one labeled copypaste.zip https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/copy-all-date-on-form-to-clipboard-to-user-can-past-this-into-another-system.309872/ .Thank you.

This is on the module code:

```
 Option Compare Database
 Option Explicit

 Private Declare Function OpenClipboard Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function EmptyClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
 Private Declare Function CloseClipboard Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
 Private Declare Function IsClipboardFormatAvailable Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function GetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function SetClipboardData Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal wFormat As Long,         ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function GlobalAlloc Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal wFlags As Long, ByVal dwBytes As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function GlobalLock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function GlobalUnlock Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function GlobalSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hMem As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function lstrcpy Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "lstrcpyW" (ByVal lpString1       
 As Long, ByVal lpString2 As Long) As Long

 Public Sub SetClipboard(sUniText As String)
     Dim iStrPtr As Long
     Dim iLen As Long
     Dim iLock As Long
     Const GMEM_MOVEABLE As Long = &H2
     Const GMEM_ZEROINIT As Long = &H40
     Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = &HD
     OpenClipboard 0&
     EmptyClipboard
     iLen = LenB(sUniText) + 2&
     iStrPtr = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE Or GMEM_ZEROINIT, iLen)
     iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
     lstrcpy iLock, StrPtr(sUniText)
     GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
     SetClipboardData CF_UNICODETEXT, iStrPtr
     CloseClipboard
 End Sub

 Public Function GetClipboard() As String
     Dim iStrPtr As Long
     Dim iLen As Long
     Dim iLock As Long
     Dim sUniText As String
     Const CF_UNICODETEXT As Long = 13&
     OpenClipboard 0&
     If IsClipboardFormatAvailable(CF_UNICODETEXT) Then
         iStrPtr = GetClipboardData(CF_UNICODETEXT)
         If iStrPtr Then
             iLock = GlobalLock(iStrPtr)
             iLen = GlobalSize(iStrPtr)
             sUniText = String$(iLen \ 2& - 1&, vbNullChar)
             lstrcpy StrPtr(sUniText), iLock
             GlobalUnlock iStrPtr
         End If
         GetClipboard = sUniText
     End If
     CloseClipboard
 End Function
```

This is on the form code:

```
 Option Compare Database
 Option Explicit

 Private Sub Command6_Click()

     Dim strSql As String
     Dim ctl As Variant

     For Each ctl In Me.Controls

         If ctl.Tag = "?" Then
             strSql = strSql & ctl.Controls(0).Caption & " " & Nz(ctl, "") & vbNewLine
         End If

     Next

     Me.Text4 = ""
     Me.Text4 = strSql

     Me.Text7 = ""

     SetClipboard strSql

End Sub
```

Comment: "cannot seem to get it to work" means what - error message, wrong result, nothing happens? Where does user need to paste?

Comment: The text does not copy. The information is being pasted on a design tool

Answer (score 2):

That is much code for nothing. This will do:

```vb
Private Sub CommandCopy_Click()

    Dim Control As Control
    Dim Value   As String
    
    For Each Control In Me.Controls
        If Control.Tag = "?" Then
            Value = Value & Control.Caption & " " & Nz(Control.Value) & vbNewLine
        End If
    Next
    
    ' Renamed Text4.
    Me!ValueCopy.Value = Value
    Me!ValueCopy.SetFocus
    DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdCopy

End Sub
```

Comment: This code didn't work for me unfortunately. I don't necessarily need the code to copy to a text box but rather to the clip board so the data can be pasted elsewhere.

Comment: _I don't necessarily need the code to copy to a text box but rather to the clip board_ ... and that is exactly what it does. Tested and verified.